# Return the indices of "false" values in a boolean array

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

I feel like this is a really simple question but I can't find the solution.

Given a boolean array of true/false values, I need the output of all the indices with the value "false". I have a way to do this for true:

test = [ True False  True  True]

```
test1 = np.where(test)[0]
```

This returns [0,2,3], in other words the corresponding index for each true value. Now I need to just get the same thing for the false, where the output would be [1]. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `np.where(~test)` instead of `np.where(test)`.

Answer (score 1):

With `enumerate`:

```
>>> test = [True, False, True, True]
>>> [i for i, b in enumerate(test) if b]
[0, 2, 3]
>>> [i for i, b in enumerate(test) if not b]
[1]
```

Comment: You can also use an `itertools.groupby` to do both in one shot, but then the type conversion gets a bit messier

Comment: It was a little unclear, but the OP is definitely using `numpy`, so this definitely shouldn't be used

Answer (score 0):

Using explicite `np.array()`.

```
import numpy as np
test = [True, False, True, True]
a = np.array(test)
test1 = np.where(a==False)[0]    #np.where(test)[0]
print(test1)
```